# Nested ngx-bootstrap modals: problems with callback function subscribing onHidden

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I have two nested modals and i have this problem:

Every modal has a callback function to execute when he's hidden, like this:

```
//first modal
let sub = this.modalService.onHidden.subscribe(()=>{
         ... //code to be executed
         sub.unsubscribe();
})



//second modal
    let sub = this.modalService.onHidden.subscribe(()=>{
             ... //code to be executed
             sub.unsubscribe();
    })
```

The onHidden subscribe are in two different components.

When I open the second modal, I do what i have to do, and I close this, the modalService execute the specified callback for second modal, but he execute also the first. It looks like that in some way "intercept" both.

How can i fix my problem?

Comment: I would expect this: this.modalService to not be the service but a modalRef instead..? The modalRef (that you can assign when you show) is a reference to that specific instance..

Comment: I've fixed a "look-alike" problem by creating a "hide()" method for each modal and using modalRef.hide() inside this.